# What's wrong with the syntax highlighter and autocompletion in Xcode using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax-highlighting

When developing a project in *Objective-C* everything is smooth, `SourceKitService` is taking **0% of CPU**, autocompletion is almost instant.

But if I change a *Swift* code a bit, it takes many seconds to do anything (highlight syntax and check, whisper etc.) Or when i want to see an implementation of something with `cmd` shortcut, again `SourceKitService` on **xxx% of CPU** and takes seconds. Changing a character in code leads to 10 seconds of waiting to see everything is ok is too much.

*Sure I tried to delete `derivedData`, `ModuleCache`, `com.apple.dt.Xcode` etc. as advised but it is not permafix, still happening, slowing me down.*

Does anybody know how to really fix this issue or at least improve it?

Comment: You have hit a common bug that has existed since the first releases of Swift. Some code, while syntactically valid, can cause SourceKit to go nuts. Unfortunately, the best way to deal with this is to identify the exact piece of code that triggers this. Please consider submitting a bug report with your exact code as well.

Comment: Do not tell me it is a blank character somewhere in the project ...

Comment: Consider posting the original code and the modification that is triggering this. It's a complicated bug and the workaround is different for each case. I remember this but happened to me most often when dealing with generics.

Comment: that is the thing, it does not matter. I can clearly erase a line of code, undo that action and boom, 5 seconds to highlighting it again.

Comment: You don't mention what version you are using - Swift3 seems to be a LOT better for this.

Comment: It is 3.0.2, should not be a problem here.

Comment: I built every single target, nothing - there are many solutions, sometimes people think those are working (maybe does) but there is still no silver-bullet imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it had something to do with `CocoaPods`. It was copying `.h` files into the build directory and `SourceKit` was getting confused.

**I added this script to my project, and `SourceKit` stopped freaking out a bit, but it is still ridiculously slow.**

```
function removeHeaders() {  
    find $BUILD_ROOT/Debug-iphonesimulator/  -name '*.h' -exec rm -f {} \;  
}  
removeHeaders
```

Ref. [Xcode Swift Syntax Highlighting and Code Completion Completely Broken](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46223)

> Note: Unfortunately this solution breaks **debugging console** and **archiving**. So remove the script if it is needed.

Comment: Note that this will also remove `.h` files from built frameworks which effectively breaks the debugging console since it cannot load the now invalid frameworks anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend trying the [Build Time Analyzer](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode) to see if there are specific things slowing down the compiler. In my experience the main problem is complex Type inference, usually from multiple chained .maps, complex associated types and, generics.

The Swift compiler is doing a lot more and is quite a bit newer than the Objective-C compiler so it unlikely it will be as stable/fast for quite some time. I know compile time and IDE stability is something they're aware is a problem and are working to improve. Hopefully now that we have (promised) source compatibility some of this things will be fixed our greatly improved within the next year. Unfortunately we'll probably have to jump through some hoops until that point.